# How can i get from a directory string only the file name in the end?

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string>` that contain 5 files for example in index[0]  I see:

```
D:\New folder (45)\converted.avi_Automatic\Lightning 2 Length 4 [276 - 280]\000276.bmp
```

The line is :

```
label22.Text = files[_indx].ToString();
```

I want instead see in label22 : D:\New folder (45)\converted.avi_Automatic\Lightning 2 Length 4 [276 - 280]\000276.bmp to see only: 000276.bmp

Before files were _files wich is a `List<FileInfo>` so I could make `_files[_indx].FullName` or `.Name`

But now the list is `List<string>`

Comment: If `files` is a `List<string>` then you don't need to call `.ToString()` on `files[_indx]` as the item at that index is a string anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) method

```
label22.Text = Path.GetFileName(files[_indx]);
```